# sort names alphabetically using array PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i've been searching how to sort name alphabetically using array in pl sql but i found nothing. can you guys please help me what should i do? i'm a beginner programmer

```
-- MENGURUTKAN NAMA 
DECLARE
    TYPE SISWA IS
        TABLE OF VARCHAR2(25) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    NAMA SISWA;
    I INTEGER;
BEGIN
    NAMA(1) := 'Arista Destriana';
    NAMA(2) := 'Yandri Gunawan';
    NAMA(3) := 'Herry Wahyudinata';
    NAMA(4) := 'Budi Raharja';
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SEBELUM DIURUTKAN : ');
    FOR I IN 1..4 LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(NAMA(I));
    END LOOP;
    --PROSES PENGURUTAN
    
END;
/
```

Comment: You should **avoid** writing your whole question in **ALL CAPS** - this is generally considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, it's rude and offensive, and dramatically lowers your chances of folks taking their time to read your question and provide an answer. Don't do it - just don't .

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done by using a **nested table type** and the **table** function as shown in the following example.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myType IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION myFunc RETURN myType
IS
   r myType := myType();
BEGIN
  r.EXTEND(3);
    r(1) := 'c';
    r(2) := 'b';
    r(3) := 'a';
  RETURN r;
END;
/

-- unsorted
SELECT * FROM TABLE (myFunc());

-- sorted
SELECT * FROM TABLE (myFunc()) ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: "Unsorted" misses the `table` operator; other than that, yes, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to *reuse* collection and do the sorting within (see lines #12-16). It selects values from collection using `table` operator (so that its contents *looks like* it was just another table) and `order by` is applied to it. The result is stored back into the same collection with `multiset`, `cast` into the "original" collection type (Oracle's built-in `sys.odcivarchar2list`).

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     nama  SYS.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list ();
  3  BEGIN
  4     nama.EXTEND (4);
  5     nama (1) := 'Arista Destriana';
  6     nama (2) := 'Yandri Gunawan';
  7     nama (3) := 'Herry Wahyudinata';
  8     nama (4) := 'Budi Raharja';
  9
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('SEBELUM DIURUTKAN : ');
 11
 12     SELECT CAST (MULTISET (  SELECT *
 13                                FROM TABLE (nama)
 14                            ORDER BY 1) AS SYS.odcivarchar2list)
 15       INTO nama
 16       FROM DUAL;
 17
 18     FOR i IN 1 .. nama.COUNT
 19     LOOP
 20        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (nama (i));
 21     END LOOP;
 22  END;
 23  /
SEBELUM DIURUTKAN :
Arista Destriana
Budi Raharja
Herry Wahyudinata
Yandri Gunawan

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```